# Does STS 4 has yaml editor in build

Tags: spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I have downloaded latest STS 4 for windows 10 but for some reason its not detecting yml formatting errors. Do I need to include any specific plugins

Answer (score 2):

There is a YAML editor but i personally dont like it.
Therefore i would like to recommend the Yaml Editor.

In STS go to `help > eclipse marketplace`

Find: `yaml` [enter]

Install `Yaml Editor 1.4.2`
If there is a warning just select `Install anyway` and after that restart STS.

For the first time make sure to open the `.yml` file with the Yaml Editor by using `open with > Yaml Editor`

Answer (score 0):

STS 4 does not have a dedicate yaml editor. Instead it uses the 'Generic Text Editor' from Eclipse together with textmate grammar for Yaml files.

These are setup to be used with Spring Boot 'application.yml' and Cloud Foundry "manifest.yml" files explicitly. For those specific cases there is also special support for generating completions and validations specifically for those type of yaml files.

For general .yml files there is no built-in support.

I'm not sure exactly what types of files you are trying to edit, and what types of warnings or errors you were expecting. So it's hard to give much/any specific advice than this.

Comment: I used STS 3.x version where it will identify format errors in yml now I am expecting same in STS 4 looks like its not in build

Comment: Like I said is built-in for application.yml, and manifest.yml files. Not for others, without knowing the types of files you want to edit there really isn't much to verify.